# Ajax's response get a void array of objects from php page

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax

### Ajax's response get a void array after i send the response by echo 'json_encode'

> Hi, I use ajax to append the elements `<option>` in `<select id='ig'>`
>   if user change the value of `<select id='if'>`. But, the response gets
>   an avoid array.

[image]

> NB: The request of select in classes Traitement and Dataaccess is work well, because i test it in postman.

[image]

**HTML:**

```
<div>
            Choisir une filiere : <select id="if">
                    <?php
                        include_once"Traitement.php"; 
                        $cur=Traitement::getAllFiliere();
                        while($row=$cur->fetch()){
                            echo"<option value='$row[0]'>$row[1]</option>";
                        }
                        $cur->closeCursor();
                    ?>
            </select>
            choisir un groupe:<select id="ig">
            </select>
</div>
```

**Javascrip:**

```
<script>
            $("#if").change(function(){
                let filiere=$("#if").val();
                $.ajax({
                    url:"reponse-ajax.php",
                    type:"POST",
                    data:"fil="+filiere,
                    dataType:"JSON"
                }).done(function(res){
                    $("#ig").html("");
                    let i=0;
                    for(i in res.groupe){
                        $("#ig").append("<option value='"+res.groupe[i].id+"'>"+res.groupe[i].nom+"</option>");
                    }
                })
            });
</script>
```

**PHP: Page -> response-ajax.php**

```
<?php
include_once"Traitement.php";
if(isset($_POST['fil'])){
    $cur1=Traitement::getGroupe($_POST['fil']);
    $res['groupe']=array();
    while($row=$cur1->fetch()){
        $lign=array();
        $lign['id']=$row[0];
        $lign['nom']=$row[1];
        array_push($res['groupe'],$lign);
    }
    echo json_encode($res);
    $cur1->closeCursor();

}
```

**PHP: Page -> Traitement.php**

```
class Traitement {
    //put your code here
    static function getGroupe($fil){
        return $cur= Dataaccess::selection("select g.* from groupe g, filiere f where g.idfil=f.idfil and f.nom='$fil'");
    }
static function getAllFiliere(){
        return $cur= Dataaccess::selection("select idfil,nom from filiere");
    }
```

Comment: What's the purpose of the image with of your code? It looks like you've added that code as text as well, with some minor adjustments. Which version should we care about?

Comment: Also, when you say "void array", do you mean an _empty_ array? Have you outputted the generated query to see if it looks correct? Have you dumped out the posted value to see if it looks correct?

Comment: You also have a big security issue. You're passing in a completely unescaped string directly into your sql query. That leaves you wide open for [SQL injection attacks](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/SQL_Injection). I don't know what database library you're using, but you should use one that uses [prepared statements](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) with placeholders.

Comment: The purpose of the image with of your code is means array is empty.<br>I try to print the array using print_r in php page 'response-ajaxe.php' and i found the array not empty it full objects. the problem in <script> tag content. it's seem like i don't have the control in javascript some time. like a someone control what will execute and what not. think the anti-virus do that. Because, it add a <script> tag every time i execute the browser.<br/> The added script is <script src="http://gc.kis.v2.scr.kaspersky-labs.com/...." etc.

Comment: Personally, I've never heard of anti virus software replacing a json array with data to an empty json array when browsing. Do you have any browser plugins from kaspersky-labs? If yes, disable it when you're working locally.

Comment: I still don't get the purpose of the image?

Comment: Yes i have a plugin from kasperskey, i disabled it. but, it no difference. When i try to output the table in **done()** on **console.log()** it dosen't work. it like **done()**'s code don't execute.